Geospark replacement and missing repository
I've been using GeoSpark some time ago, but now I can see its documentation is not available under its past address on github and can't find it anywhere.
What happened to: https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/ and where can I find a replacement?

GeoSpark has joined the Apache Software Foundation 4 years ago and became Apache Sedona.
Here is the new GitHub repo: https://github.com/apache/sedona
Here is the new website: https://sedona.apache.org/
